# Android Storage Directories

Tags: android, storage, directory

I am developing an application in which i have to get all available storage directories on device, like file directory, on Board storage, external sdCard storage (Removable)

but the storage path varies device to device such as
i have Samsung Galaxy tab 7 with Froyo2.2 that has these three storage

1: Files Directory
/mnt/.lfs,

2: OnBoard Storage Directory
/mnt/sdcard,

3: External sdCard Removeable Storage Directory
/mnt/sdcard/external_sd

i am getting these using this code

```
    public static String[] getDirectories()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "getStorageDirectories");
            File tempFile;
            String[] directories = null;
            String[] splits;
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            String lineRead;

            try
                {
                    arrayList.clear(); // redundant, but what the hey
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));

                    while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "lineRead: " + lineRead);
                            splits = lineRead.split(" ");

                            // System external storage
                            if (splits[1].equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()))
                                {
                                    arrayList.add(splits[1]);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "gesd split 1: " + splits[1]);
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // skip if not external storage device
                            if (!splits[0].contains("/dev/block/"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // skip if mtdblock device

                            if (splits[0].contains("/dev/block/mtdblock"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // skip if not in /mnt node

                            if (!splits[1].contains("/mnt"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // skip these names

                            if (splits[1].contains("/secure"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            if (splits[1].contains("/mnt/asec"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // Eliminate if not a directory or fully accessible
                            tempFile = new File(splits[1]);
                            if (!tempFile.exists())
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            if (!tempFile.isDirectory())
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            if (!tempFile.canRead())
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            if (!tempFile.canWrite())
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            // Met all the criteria, assume sdcard
                            arrayList.add(splits[1]);
                        }

                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
            finally
                {
                    if (bufferedReader != null)
                        {
                            try
                                {
                                    bufferedReader.close();
                                }
                            catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                }
                        }
                }

            // Send list back to caller

            if (arrayList.size() == 0)
                {
                    arrayList.add("sdcard not found");
                }
            directories = new String[arrayList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    directories[i] = arrayList.get(i);
                }
            return directories;
        }
```

but when i run this code on Nexus7 4.2.2 Jelly Beans it returns only one path at runtime how may i know what path is this

and this storage paths varies among different devices

i have to identify onBoard storage if available user can select device storage
if external sdcard available then user can select onBoard or external storage